# Swift: Cannot override method with custom class return type that implements Objectmappers Mappable

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I want to override a method defined in a Parent class, that results a custom class.

The Parent:

```
open class PagedTableViewController<T>: UIViewController {
    open func getSelectedFilters () -> SelectedFiltersResource {
        return SelectedFiltersResource()
    }
}
```

When i try to override it in the child class, i get the error message "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

The Child looks like this:

```
class ReshipmentsTabViewController: 
PagedTableViewController<Reshipment> { 
    //This does NOT work
    override func getSelectedFilters() -> SelectedFiltersResource { 
        return SelectedFiltersResource() 
    } 
    //This DOES work (if i also change the type in the parent obv.)
    override func getSelectedFilters() -> String { 
        return String() 
    } 
}
```

This makes no sense to me, since the child obviously does override the function. 
I tried switching the Return type to String, and then it worked. So i guess my result type is the problem:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

open class SelectedFiltersResource: NSObject, Mappable {

    public var selectedCustomers = [Int64]()

    public override init() {
    }

    public required init?(map: Map) {
    }

    // Mappable
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        selectedCustomers           <- map["selectedCustomers"]
    }
}
```

So what is the Problem here? I cant see any... I use Swift 5.0 and Xcode 10.2
My SelectedFilters class and the Parent class come from a Cocoapod.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share Reshipment class details.

Comment: i do not think it has anything todo with it. If i replace reshipment with String or sth else, it still wont work.

Comment: I don't know why but when I removed `Mappable` and related code from `SelectedFiltersResource` the override works.

Comment: Hm thanks, thats a hint at least